# Can I use a custom icon instead of the dots in a secure UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1

The dots `iOS7.1` uses for `Secure Text Fields` are bigger than the previous ones and are pretty ugly.

Can I use a `different icon` instead of these standard dots? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: If you're asking that can the default dots in `secureTextEntry` be replaced by another character, then it's not possible. The best you can do is create a complex code to keep a string to store characters as they are typed, or use `addSubview` in `textField` (since it inherits from `UIView`).

Comment: YES! You can use unicode characters to show them to user and take a separate `NSMutableString` to contains the exact password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
/* don't ever use this PROOF OF CONCEPT CODE for production use */
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{   
if ( self.backing == nil ) self.backing = @"";
static BOOL pasting = false;

if ( !pasting )
{       
    self.backing = [self.backing stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"backing: %@",self.backing);
    if ( [string length] == 0 ) return YES; // early bail out when just deleting chars

    NSString *sec = @"";
    for ( int i=0;i<[string length]; i++ ) sec = [sec stringByAppendingFormat:@"■"];

    pasting = true;
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:sec];
    [textField paste:self];

    return NO;  
} else {
    pasting = false;
    return YES; 
}       
}
```

Comment: What is self.backing?

Comment: @iDeveloper You just pasted the same code as link's code here. Instead you should have pasted the link as comment.